# Why can't a hash map be static..?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

why is this syntax not legal..? Can you throw some light on what is the design issue in not allowing HashMap to be static with declarations like this.?

```
static HashMap<String,  String> map2 = new HashMap<String,  String> ();
```

Comment: It´s allowed... What error do you get?

Comment: Agreed - there is no issue with it being static

Comment: Illegal modifier for parameter map2; only final is permitted   this is the error i am getting...

Comment: looks like you're trying to declare map2 within method.

Comment: @sasidhar: you have this in the method level. No method local variables can be static.

Comment: did you pass map2 as a parameter with the static keyword? Are you sure the error is on that line?

Comment: @Nivas i have this at method level agreed... but the method itself is static, isn't it allowed like that even.?

Comment: No, you cannot declare a static variable inside a method, even if the method is static.  This isn't C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
static HashMap<String,  String> map2 = new HashMap<String,  String> ();
```

is perfectly valid provided you have this code at the class level and not in a method.

Where do you have this?

**After your update:**

You have the variable declared at the method level, static variables are not allowed at the method level.

`static` variables are *class* variables. One per class. So it does not make sense to have variables that are visible only inside a method, that is going to *die* after the method is done, to be 'class level'. At least thats how Java sees it.

Answer (score 11):

That declaration is perfectly legal on its own. I can think of two reasons why you'd get an error:

- You put that declaration somewhere where static declarations are not allowed (e.g. inside a method).
- You did not import `java.util.HashMap` (of course in that case the error has nothing to do with your use of the `static` keyword).

Comment: +1 - The first bullet identifies the problem - see @sasidhar's comment about an "illegal modifier" error.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of `HashMap` is completely correct, maybe you're trying to use it from a non-static context/method?

Answer (score 0):

We can declare any collection in java as static.So there is nothing wrong in your declaration.

```
static HashMap<String,  String> map2 = new HashMap<String,  String> ();
```